# UWP How to reduce speed or set animation when entering full screen mode

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to enter full screen mode with below code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    if (view.IsFullScreenMode)
    {
        view.ExitFullScreenMode();
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Auto;
    }
    else
    {
        if (view.TryEnterFullScreenMode())
        {
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
        }
    }
}
```

When entering full screen mode, I see the unexpected blue color display.

Maybe the speed when change size from normal to full screen is too fast.

And my app is weight, so full screen cannot be loaded in time.

Therefore, is there any way to reduce the speed when entering full screen?

or create an animation like StoryBoard with duration?

Comment: I try to use `TryResizeView` to modify the size of the current page to maximize the page. However, when page is maximized, it cannot cover the taskbar below, so the blue background will appear below when entering full screen. I think this is a system behavior and there is currently no good way to solve it.

Comment: I tried to use TryResizeView with width and height are get from DisplayInformation. (WidthPixel/pixel, HeightPixel/pixel). But app size can not resize. For ex my monitor display is (1366,768). TryResizeView(1366,768) or TryResizeView(1200,700) can not be effect. But TryResizeView(1100,600) is OK. Why?

Comment: In short, you have to consider the height of the taskbar, The maximum height value is (monitor height - taskbar height). It is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview?view=winrt-22621#remarks), If the resize forces parts of the app to go outside of available work area, the system will move it back into the available work area.

Comment: Hi Junjie Zhu, May I inherit or get source code of the default maximum button on title bar of window? ( When I click it, it make the screen wide very smooth. )