# Triggering Minimize, Maximize, Close Actions in UWP Title Bar

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In UWP, is it possible to simulate or trigger the actions of minimize/maximize/close buttons that are usually present in the title bar by pressing a different button in my application?

If it's possible, I'd appreciate a detailed explanation on how to implement this since the direct commands used in WPF, like `SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand`, or `SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand` from `System.Windows`, do not seem to exist in UWP.

[image]

Comment: set your border to none and make buttons with the images, you can then call the command as you do any other ICommand

Comment: Closely related question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020408/minimize-uwp-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maximize the window, you can add the following code to any button of your choice. It retrieves the current view and then attempts to switch to full-screen mode.

```cs
// Get the current view
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

// Check if the view is in full screen
if (!view.IsFullScreenMode) view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

To close the application, use the following code on a button:

```cs
Application.Current.Exit();
```

To minimize the app window you can use the new API (from here: [Minimize UWP programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020408/minimize-uwp-programmatically))

```cs
IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();
IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();
await resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();
```

Comment: I have a problem with TryEnterFullScreenMode(), so I want to resolve it by triggering max button in title bar because this max process animation is smooth. My problem is described at     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139765/uwp-how-to-reduce-speed-or-set-animation-when-entering-full-screen-mode

Comment: @rickyrocky Currently, UWP has no relevant API to realize the function of max button. I know you want to reduce the impact of blue flashing, I haven't found a better way yet. Even if the app is maximized, there is still a blue flashing on the taskbar when the app enters full screen mode.

Comment: @Junjie Zhu  Thanks!  :(